# Tomcat returns not the same path of current directory as JUnit tests returns

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, junit

First of all excuse me for my ugly English. 
I have some problem with loading properties file into object of java.lang.Properties in my web application. Maybe it will be appear as stupid question, but I can't resolve it myself.
So I have this code snippet:
`String path = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();`
When I run tests, value of variable **path** was equals to absolute path of my project root directory, as I expected (in my case it is "D:\ProgsJava\persons-web"). But when I have started my app in Eclipse using Tomcat, and one of servlets has invoked this code snippet the value of variable **path** was equals to absolute path of directory in which IDE has been installed (in my case it is "D:\soft\Eclipse"). I have fix this problem by entering absolute path of properties file but it is not correct solution. All dependencies have been injected by maven. Could you explain me what is the magic with pathes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If you want to get the path of the project directory , try the following code snippet

System.getProperty("user.dir");